# Undefined control sequence \tl_gput_right:Ne

Tags: errors, expl3

A user reported to me that when using the document class `Q-and-A`, an error of `Undefined control sequence` occurs:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tl_gput_right:Ne 
                             \g_QA_content_tl {\exp_not:N \begin {QA_\l__QA_...
l.52 \end
         {document}
```

I presume this means that `\tl_gput_right:Ne` is undefined here? But according to `interface3.pdf`, this `e`-variant seems to be predefined:

[image]

Since I cannot replicate this error, I believe that some of the package may not have been fully up-to-dated. But according to the log file, the document class is the newest one, and the LaTeX2e and expl3 version seem to be newly enough. So what could be the possible cause of this issue?

Here is the [full log file](https://gist.github.com/chenboshuo/92112f8d5c7afbd73ed409e290e4ea72) provided.

Comment: the whole system of the user is older, everything is from the start of the year. The only really new thing is the class `2023/11/19` and the various e-variants have just been added a few months ago to the l3layer.

Comment: It never hurts to add generation of variants you use, the declaration will be ignored on newer systems where it is already declared.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the information! By the way, for compatibility issue, do you think that perhaps I should add a `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` in my document class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see. Thank you for this!